# param is missing or the value is empty: accessproject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in rails. I have a problem with param accessproject. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk5K2.png)

I'm create migration inner table with *project_id* and *user_id*

```
class Accessproject < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Action *index* in controller *Accessproject* open two views

class AccessprojectController < ApplicationController

```
def index
    if params[:project_id]
        @accessproject = Project.find(params[:project_id]).users
        render "accessproject/indexaccessprojects.html"
    elsif params[:user_id]
        @accessuser = User.find(params[:user_id]).projects
        render "accessproject/indexaccessusers.html"
    else
    end 
end
```

In view create form_tag with open list of user

## Пользователи

```
<% @accessproject.each do |user| %>

    <h3><%= user.last_name + " " + user.first_name %></h3>

<% end %>



 <%= form_tag @access do |f| %>
      <div class="well well-lg">    
        <h4>Добавить пользователя</h4>
        <p><%= select("accessprojects", "user_id", User.all.collect {|p| [ p.last_name + " " + p.first_name , p.id ] }, {prompt: 'Пользователь'})  %>
<%= submit_tag "Сохранить", ({:class => 'btn btn-primary'}) %>  </p>    </div>

    <% end %>
```

Next step i create action create and have a problem

```
def create
        @access = Accessproject.new(user_id: params.require(:accessproject).require(:user_id), project_id: params.require(:project_id))
    end
```

Can help with this problem?

Comment: You have many issues in the code. `form_tag` should be `form_for`, `accessprojects` should be `accessproject` and the way you are adding strong params is completely wrong.